# emacsclient of 24.4 does not work on Yosemite

Tags: emacsclient, osx, emacs24.4

I have used emacsclient without any problem on OSX. Usually I just start Emacs server by `emacs --daemon` in Console, and then `emacsclient` works. I use `emacsclient -nc` to create a new frame. However, after upgrading to Emacs 24.4, emacsclient just hangs on without printing any info when invoking the command. I tried both http://emacsformacosx.com/ and `brew install`, and I had the same problem. Can anyone help to look at this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried it without any user configuration files and/or additional libraries to see if it works out-of-the-box -- i.e. emacs -Q?  Have you tried it from the directory where the new installation of emacs is located (or with the absolute path) to make sure you are calling the right version?  OSX ships with an older version.

Comment: I forgot emacs -Q... Yes the bare Emacs looks ok. Must be something messed up in my config files. Thank you.

Comment: There appears to be a problem with Emacs under OS X, where Emacs hangs on startup about 10% of the times. Maybe you were just unlucky when you tried it.

Answer (score 6):

May well be due to you're using the wrong `emacsclient`. I had the same  (i.e.,
`can't find socket` and/or `-error Unknown&_command:&_THEFILENAME`
Turned out I used `/usr/bin/emacsclient`, whereas my emacs is actually `~/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` . Creating a symlink from `~/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient` to a place on my `$PATH` that precedes `/usr/bin` solved it. See http://www.citizen428.net/blog/2010/09/22/emacsclient-on-os-x/
BTW this is `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS apple-appkit-1348.17)`, `OSX Yosemite version 10.10.5`